# Protecting your computer from trackers via email and websites

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, email

I have noticed that Kijiji.com block or deletes accounts from people who advertise outside the area you live in. When Kijiji Canada was born there was only Calagary for our area, then enough people made request to add another location Banff/Canmore. The problem that arose there is that now the Banff/Canmore residents do not have the option of advertising in Calgary. I am trying to circumvent this somehow. I was wondering, can other people get your mac address from emails links, opening an email, sending and email or by submitting a form from a website? Thanks in advance!

I am running Lubuntu on a Roger's cisco wireless router

Answer (score 1):

- People can not get your MAC address by any of the suggested ways.
  Even if they do, they can not deduce where you reside from your MAC
  address.
- People can get your MAC address when you visit their
  server if your PC and server reside in the same Ethernet or WiFi
  network.
- People can get your IP address when you visit links on
  their site or sometimes when you read email from them. People can
  assume the city or even city block where you reside by your IP
  address.
- The only way to deal with service where you do not agree
  with imposed terms in not to use it and openly ask others not to use
  it, providing reasons. In **any** other case you will loose
  eventually.

Comment: Barafu Albino:  Thank you kindly, that clears up a few things.